# Very hard to select text via mouse accurately after upgraded to Yosemite

Tags: macos, mouse, accessibility

After upgraded to Yosemite, I've found that the mouse selection is basically broken, e.g. when I select, I follow the steps

1. mouse down, start select
2. end select, mouse up

The problem is, when I mouse up in step2, basically what I selected, has 50% of chance is being unselected.

I can't reproduce the issue every time, but given that 50% of chance, it is very annoying..

Any idea?

Comment: I haven't seen this issue, but do you have a bluetooth mouse? I've noticed that in Yosemite there's some issue that causes bluetooth mice to stutter occasionally for no real reason (not load related at least). Might be related to what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

regardless from the type of mouse you are using, try going into settings/mouse options and feel free to fiddle with the settings here, when I had trackpad tracking issues after the update (couldn't even move the pointer arrow properly), I just went there and changed the cursor sensitivity and that did the trick.

Hope it works for you too!